# error while creating a new ruby on rails project using command rails new myapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4.2

When i try to create a new project using command "rails new myapp" it gives the following error (earlier i successfully created many projects using same command):-

[image]
[image]

**and the following error occurs when my pc is connected to the internet :-**

run  bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

```
     run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

- bin/rake: spring inserted
- bin/rails: spring inserted

**please suggest a solution**

Answer (score 1):

As part of creating a new rails application rails sets up a Gemfile for you and does `bundle install` to install the gems required for the basic application you have just created.

Your errors are because when it tries to do `bundle install` it cannot reach the rubygems to download the gems it wants to (in your first example because you are not connected to the internet and in the second because for some reason your computer cannot connect to rubygems.org).

As for the specific reason why you can't connect that could be for many reasons. Are you behind a firewall? Is https available?

You can try calling `bundle install` yourself rather than as part of the rails process. Adding `--verbose` should generate some extra logging information which may help to diagnose the problem.

You can also try install gems manually to see if that works okay. You must have done this yourself at some point to get the rails gem installed.

Comment: what all gems are required in this case that are not present? how can i recognise them from this error message?

Comment: If you do `bundle list` it will tell you the gems that bundler cannot find.